# Word Break Problem - How to proceed after creating an array/matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the Word Break problem on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) and have reached a point wherein I have the following matrix `A` that contains `True` if the sequence of letters forms a word on the dictionary and `False` otherwise.

Code to create the array is below:

```
word = "catsandog"
wordDict = set(["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"])

n = len(word)

A = [[False] * n for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        if j > i:
            if word[i:j] in wordDict:
                 A[i][i:j] = [True] * len(A[i][i:j])
```

However I am unable to figure out how to proceed from here. I understand the output of the code should be `False` since "cats", "and", "og" is not a space separated word and neither is "cat", "sand", "og", but I am unable to figure how do I incorporate this logic using my matrix `A`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how the matrix brings you closer to the solution. Even if a row in that matrix has all `True` in it, it does not mean there is a solution. And if there were a solution, this row does not tell you which words form the solution. I don't think you should proceed with this idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need 2D matrix for this, here is the simple approach that I'll use.

```
def wordBreak(s: str, words: List[str]) -> bool:
    dp = [True] + [False] * len(s) # dp[i] means s[:i+1] can be segmented into words
        
    dp[0] = True
        
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            if dp[i] and s[i: j+1] in words:
                dp[j+1] = True     #
                
                
                    
    return dp[-1]
    

s = "atepietea"
words = ["tea", "pie", "ate"]
print(wordBreak(s, words))          # True
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Daniel. However the code you have written does not work for the example in the question. The function should return `False` however your code returns `True` which is not right.

Comment: @parzival123 - update done and all test passed. It should work now. Please check... Thanks.